# GDAL contour line generation at DEM edges

Tags: gdal, dted, gdal-contour

In a Python application I use gdal.ContourGenerate() to generate contour lines (GDAL version 1.11.4 and 2.2.1) from DTED tiles. DTED tiles overlap at the top and the right with neighboring tiles.

Comparing contour lines build from several individual DTED tiles to these, build from a VRT show discrepancies at the tile edges. That is because contour lines are extended perpendicular to the tile borders. That is the reason, why contour lines from neighboring tiles do not meet at the same position.

[image]

According the documentation this shouldn't be the case:

> This means that contour lines' nodes will not actually be on pixel
>   edges, but rather along vertical and horizontal lines connecting the
>   pixel centers.

Is there a way to restrict contour line generation to the area between raster cell centers?

Comment: I had the same issue and used following (PostGIS) SQL command to remove first and last point of all non-closed contours: `update contour set way = ST_RemovePoint(ST_RemovePoint(way, ST_NPoints(way) - 1), 0) where ST_IsClosed(way) = false;`

Comment: @Detlev Did you ever find a solution this problem?